# Jack compiler seems to ignore encoding compile option

Tags: android, android-studio, jack-compiler

I recently upgraded an Android project to use use the Jack compiler:

```
jackOptions {
  enabled true
}
```

It uses box-drawing characters that are embedded in source files as string literals.  Everything was fine pre-Jack.  I used:

```
compileOptions {
  encoding "UTF-8"
  // {snip}
}
```

and the box drawing characters appeared at runtime.  After upgrading to Jack, it renders as corrupted Unicode-interpreted-as-ASCII (?): **â”,** instead of **│**

I can work around this by using Unicode escapes (**\u2502**), but it's a bit odd that a brand new compiler for Java doesn't support Unicode...  Is there another option that Jack recognizes to accept UTF-8 encoded source files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a [known issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=218892) with the current release of jackjill